# How to replace if http or https using sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have these following string in my `.htaccess`:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?language=french 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Here is my expected output:

```
https://altwww.example.com/index.php?language=french 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^altwww.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://altwww.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I have tried the following :

```
old_domain="https?:\/\/www"
new_domain="https?:\/\/altwww"
sed -i -e "s/\${old_domain}/${new_domain}/g" /path/to/my/.htaccess
```

Comment: Remove the `^` which only matches the beginning of the line.

Comment: @TobiasFendin Updated but I'm getting the same output

Comment: have you tried replacing 'www.example.com' with 'altwww.example.com'?

Comment: Please add the details on what you are really doing as you mention some very peculiar details in [the comments](https://imgur.com/a/tx5rbLN).

Comment: I'm pulling from git and I need to update the .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
old_domain='(https?:\/\/)(https?:\/\/)?www'
new_domain='\1altwww'
old_domain2='(\^)(altwww\.)?([[:alnum:]][^ ]*\.com)'
new_domain2='\1altwww.\3'

sed -i -E "s/${old_domain}/${new_domain}/g;s/${old_domain2}/${new_domain2}/g" /path/to/my/.htaccess
```

The `-E` option enables the POSIX ERE syntax.

The `(https?:\/\/)(https?:\/\/)?www` pattern matches and captures into Group 1 `http://` or `https://`, then matches an optional `http://` or `https://` again (to avoid duplicating) and then matches `www`. The replacement, `\1altwww`, replaces the match with the contents of Group 1 and `www` appended to it.

The second command looks for a `^` (captured into Group 1) that is followed with an optional `altwww.` string (Group 2) and then has an alphanumeric char, zero or more non-space chars and then a `.com` captured into Group 3 (with `(\^)(altwww\.)?([[:alnum:]][^ ]*\.com)`) and replaces with Group 1 value + `altwww.` + Group 3 value.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/BdhOAP).

Comment: If I run the command twice I got double `altwww` in this following line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^altwww.altwww.example.com [NC]`

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work for all cases:

`sed -e 'sN\(http\(s\|\)://www.\|\)example.comN\1altwww.example.comN' .htaccess`

Old invalid answer:
This command changes all occurances of http[s]://www.example.com to the host altwww:

`sed -e 'sN\(https?://\)wwwN\1altwwwN' .htaccess`

But if you want to change all occurances of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) you can use

`sed -e 'sNexample.comNaltwww.example.comN' .htaccess`

Comment: The first command doesn't change anything and the second command gives me the following `https://www.altwww.example.com` instead of `https://altwww.example.com`

Comment: Well it ovveride if I run it twice I have for example: `https://altwww.altwww.example.com`

Comment: Yes it will. If you need to execute it twice I guess you need to split it into two separate substitutions